# Can't access property of existing service in component

Tags: angular, service, constructor, components

I have created a service simple service which loads at first a configuration  from a JSON file. Because I want that the data is available when the app is started, I'm using the APP_INITIALIZER to load the data.

In the service itself the data is available and everything is fine. But when I use the service from inside a component it gets a strange behaviour. Please can somebody explain whats wrong with my code?

**filterService.ts**

```
export class FilterService {
   url:string = '/admin2/src/assets/import.filter.json';
   filters: Filter[];
   currentFilter: Filter;

   public loadFilters() {

      this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(response => {
        this.filters = <Filter[]>response;

        if (this.filters[0])
            this.currentFilter  = this.filters[0];
    });
}
```

this service is loaded during app init

**app.module.ts**

```
 @NgModule({
 ...
 providers: [
    FilterService,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: (filterService: FilterService) => () => filterService.loadFilters(), deps: [FilterService], multi: true },
 ],
 ...
```

Finally, in my component I'm doing:

**filter.component.ts**

```
constructor(private filterService: FilterService) {}

ngOnInit() { 
    console.log('import initialized'); 

    console.log(this.filterService);
    console.log(this.filterService.currentFilter);
    console.log(this.filterService.filters);
    console.log(this.filterService.getFilters());
}
```

And now I really don't understand what is happen in the console.log

```
  Object { http: {…}, url: "http://...}   // as expected
  undefined                               // ??                               
  undefined                               // ??
  undefined                               // ??
```

Why can't I access the object properties? It looks to me that everything is fine and available....

Comment: you should "return this.http.get(this.url)" in the service file ... and in the component.ts file: you should do the subscribe... the reason you are getting undefined is because the async code hasn't finished loading and you tried to print the value... create an example on stackblitz and someone will guide you through if you're stuck

Comment: That I do understand and this was also my first approach. But in the end I want to have the data available in the service without using subscribe(). In general the output is very strange to me: in the one hand sind the colsole.log() shows me the object but as soon as I try to access a property it is undefined. I never have seen such behaviour before...

Comment: if you create a stackblitz, the sO community can help identify the cause...

Answer (score 0):

In your case =>

#### app-load.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

import { FilterService } from './filter.service';

export function load_filters(filterService: FilterService) {
    return () => filterService.loadFilters();
}

export function get_filters(filterService: FilterService) {
    return () => filterService.getFilters();
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    AppLoadService,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: load_filters, deps: [FilterService], multi: true },
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: get_filters, deps: [FilterService], multi: true }
  ]
})
export class AppLoadModule { }
```

#### app.module.ts

```
import { AppLoadModule } from './app-load/app-load.module';
@NgModule({
     imports: [AppLoadModule]
 })
```

I have followed this blog to create my APP_INITIALIZER => Please read it once(may be useful)
https://www.intertech.com/Blog/angular-4-tutorial-run-code-during-app-initialization/